# Write a function accepting wrapped constants, but only one level deep

Tags: prolog

I want to write a function (*apologies for probably not using the correct term here*) `wubble` which is true for specific constants *and* true for those constants if wrapped into another constant, but only one layer deep! Examples:

```
% are supposed to be TRUE:
?- wubble(foo).
?- wubble(bar).
?- wubble(wrapper(foo)).
?- wubble(wrapper(bar)).

% are suppoed to be FALSE:
?- wubble(not_in_knowledge_base).
?- wubble(wrapper(wrapper(foo))).
```

The naive (at least in my brain) implementation looks like this:

```
wubble(foo).
wubble(bar).

wubble(wrapper(wrapper(_))) :- !, fail.
wubble(wrapper(X)) :- wubble(X).
```

And this works with the queries above. However, I can't enumerate all valid `X` for `wubble` with this implementation:

```
?- wubble(X).
X = foo
X = bar
```

So this is missing `X = wrapper(foo)` and `X = wrapper(bar)`. Is it possible to fix my implementation somehow?

Comment: I found a solution: `wubble(wrapper(X)) :- wubble(X), ((X = wrapper(_), !, fail); true).`. But I don't exactly understand how it works. It would be super awesome if someone could write an answer explaining my solution and maybe provide a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could separate the facts from the rules:

```
wubble_(foo).
wubble_(bar).

wubble(X) :- wubble_(X).
wubble(wrapper(X)) :- wubble_(X).
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution in this particular case, as the OP noted himself, is the following:

```
wubble(foo).
wubble(bar).

wubble(wrapper(X)) :- wubble(X), ((X = wrapper(_), !, fail); true).
```

Since he also asked for an explanation of this pattern, here is my best shot:

Given the above knowledge base, a query like `wubble(X).` looks through it from top to bottom for either facts or heads of rules that unify with the goal, `wubble(X)`. If it finds a fact, like `wubble(foo)`, the goal just succeeds, unifying `X` with the inner term of the fact, in this case `foo`. After that, we can tell Prolog to backtrack to the last *choice point* (a node in the depth first search tree that Prolog builds during this process), which in this case was given by the original goal `wubble(X)` and make it look for other solutions to that goal. If we do this here, we get the fact for the second constant `wubble(bar)` of course.

Now for the fun part. If we backtrack again, the only way left to satisfy the goal `wubble(X)` is by satisfying the antecedent of your rule. Now let's go through this mechanically. This might be surprising, but `wubble(wrapper(X))` unifies with `wubble(X)`; you have to think of these `X`es as independent. Both in the case of the query `wubble(X)` and the rule definition `wubble(wrapper(X)) :- ...`, `X` is just a local name. Really, these two variables are independent, uninstantiated variables in this situation and since an uninstantiated variable unifies with basically everything, we have `X = wrapper(X)` and thus the head of the rule matches our query. Maybe we should call them `X1` and `X2` for the query and the rule respectively, for now.

Now the tail of the rule is a conjunction, so we first try to satisfy the first goal, `wubble(X)`, which creates a new choice point. Now the process basically starts over: We search the knowledge base from top to bottom for stuff that unifies with that, which first finds `wubble(foo)`. So `X2` is now unified with `foo` and we check whether the second part of the conjunction, now with `X2 = foo`, succeeds, which it does, because `foo \= wrapper(_)`. So because both goals of the conjunction succeeded with `X2 = foo`, our original goal succeeds as well with `X1 = wrapper(X2) = wrapper(foo)`.

Backtracking from this basically brings us back to the second choice point, created by the first goal of the conjunction in the rule. Next, we find `X2 = bar`, which again checks out with the second part of the conjunction and our original goal succeeds with `X1 = wrapper(bar)`.

Next, we get to the rule again; we unify `X2 = wrapper(X3)`, our new goal is `wubble(X3)`, creating a new choice point, and this succeeds with `X3 = foo` and the second part also checks out. So now we go one layer up and we have `X2 = wrapper(foo)`. This does not satisfy the second part of the conjunction! It triggers the `!, fail`, so our original goal of `wubble(X1)`, where we unified `X1 = wrapper(X2) = wrapper(wrapper(foo))`, **fails** this time. But not only that, we also cut, which eliminates the choice point of the first recursive `kipple` call and everything below it, so we don't even try `X3 = bar` or `X3 = wrapper(X4)` anymore.

So we go back further to our original choice point for the goal `wubble(X1)`; but there are no further clauses in the database that match this, so we are done.

Now I get that this might be hard to follow in text form, so here is my attempt to visualize the search tree:

[image: Search three for the query <code>wubble(X)</code>. Red signifies what the cut ... well cuts.]

Comment: Care to explain the downvote, dear anonymous downvoter? :)